# How do I use Azure Resouce Provider to receive payments for my service?

Tags: azure, cloud, azure-store

[This is Windows Azure Resource Provider SDK](https://github.com/WindowsAzure/azure-resource-provider-sdk). I've tried to read about [concepts](https://github.com/WindowsAzure/azure-resource-provider-sdk/blob/master/docs/concepts.md) and can't definitely understand whether it allows me to do what I want.

I have a web service that is hosted in Windows Azure. Users get a userid-password pair, pay for the service via PayPal and then they can make web requests to a designated URL providing their userid-password pairs and the service will deduct funds based on number of their requests. When they pay via PayPal they buy "right to make N requests" - their balance inside the service is increased by the "number of requests" they paid for. So it's a pay-per-usage-volume service.

Now I want to expose my service to the Azure Store using the Resource Provider SDK charging people for the number of requests they make to my service.

The [concepts](https://github.com/WindowsAzure/azure-resource-provider-sdk/blob/master/docs/concepts.md) document says

> The user then creates a Subscription. A Subscription is a named entity e.g. 3-month Free Trial or MyApp Production. You can view your own Subscriptions on the Account Portal.
>
> Next, the user creates one or more Resources such as a Website or Virtual Machine. Website and Virtual Machine are two different ResourceTypes. Each Resource is deployed under exactly one Subscription.

The subscription part is more or less clear. What about `Resource` objects? I mean the description continues "such as a Web Site or Virtual Machine" but what I want to offer is not a site and not a VM, it's a right to queue a certain number of requests to my service URL.

Either I don't get something simple or the Azure Resource Provider SDK is just not what I can use.

How do I expose my pay-per-usage-volume service to Azure Store using Azure Resource Provider SDK?

Comment: I've forwarded this question to http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2013/01/23/windows-azure-store-new-add-ons-and-expanded-availability.aspx?CommentPosted=true#commentmessage. Hopefully we'll get an answer.

Answer (score 1):

All the confusion is because how the documentation is worded. It says

> The user then creates a Subscription. A Subscription is a named entity e.g. 3-month Free Trial or MyApp Production.

This is partially true. The user indeed creates a subscription but that typically happens long before he makes his first purchase from Azure Store. Subscriptions are Azure thing, they are not specific to Azure Store. What the RP sees is the subscription id (currently in form of GUID string representation) and by the subscription id the RP can distinguish between purchases made by different users.

Then goes this

> Next, the user creates one or more Resources such as a Website or Virtual Machine. Website and Virtual Machine are two different ResourceTypes. Each Resource is deployed under exactly one Subscription.

This is just very far from true.

The user chooses an "offering" from Azure Store showcase (basically a list of available services), then he selects a "plan" (which is a "you pay X money and get Y of the service" type of offer, X is zero for free plans) and he chooses a "resource name". The "resource name" is up to the user - he chooses it.

The "resource type" is a unique symbolic identifier for the "offering" which must be unique across the entire Azure Store and is chosen by the RP designer. So examples like "Websites" or "Virtual machines" are both very bad and useless - in fact you'll want to have a "resource type" like `CompanyXMalingService` so that when someone else wants to offer a "mailing service" he could offer `CompanyYMailingService` and when you yourself want to offer a "telephony service" you can use `CompanyXTelephonyService` and not collide with others.

Now if you offer something with "N requests per period" billing model you only can have "one month" as a period, so it can only be "N requests per month", nothing else. Suppose your offering "resource type" is `CompanyXCoolRequests`.

The model is then as follows: user clicks on your offering, selects a plan (for example, 1000 requests per month) and clicks through until he is billed. Meanwhile the store will send a request to your RP saying that there was a purchase for subscription with a certain id of resource of type `CompanyXCoolRequests` and with some resource name, the plan identifier will be inside the request. Your RP creates an account inside your service and debits the number of requests there, it has to provide the user id and password (or whatever stuff is needed to use your service) - either as "output items" which are displayed when the user clicks "Connection info" button or via the service page where the user is redirected when he clicks the "Manage" button.

Now there're the following options. Either just nothing happens for years and then it means the user purchase is active and he is billed every month, the month starts att he date he made a purchase and lasts till the same date of the next month. You have to provide him with 1000 requests every month. You have to decide what to do with the leftover balance (like the month is ending and he only used 800 requests) and what to do when he uses everything up before the new month starts. The user can also "delete" your offering from his subscription - he will no longer be billed ad the store will send a request to your RP and you have to delete or block the account you created earlier in you service. Also it's possible that there's a subscription-level event like suspension of the subscription - then you have to temporarily block all the resources of that subscription and be able to restore them all one the subscription is "resumed. And finally the user can "upgrade" his purchase by switching to a more expensive plan - you'll have to debit extra units to his "account" inside your service.

Answer (score 0):

The Subscription can be thought of an identifier for the Users commerce relation ship [think an identifier for which Credit Card to charge]
The Resource or The addon on the other had is what identifies the instance of the service that the user is buying.

In your case lets call your Service "SharpToothService" and the user can go to the service and buy the ability to send "n SharpTooths/month" for 9.99.

Sharp tooth would be the resource. 
& The user name and password would be the Output Items [Result of Provisioning and Purchasing the resource]

[As you get along you might have question on plans]-
Plan is what identifies the sold packagae for eg. You might have Silver plan for "100 Sharptooths for 9.99/month: a gold one for "500 SHarptooths for 19.99/month" etc